# Is it expensive to create objects?

Tags: .net, class-design

I have just refactored a colleague's code that, roughly, looked like this...

```
public class Utility
  public void AddHistoryEntry(int userID, HistoryType Historytype, int companyID)
  {
    // Do something...
  }
  public void AddHistoryEntry(int userID, HistoryType historyType, int companyID, string notes)
  {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```

To this...

```
public class HistoryEntry
{
  public long UserID { get; private set; }
  public HistoryType HistoryType { get; private set; }
  public long CompanyID { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }

  public HistoryEntry(long userID, HistoryType historyType)
  {
    this.UserID = userID;
    this.HistoryType = historyType;
  }
}

public class Utility
{
  public void AddHistoryEntry(HistoryEntry entry)
  {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```

Now, this is much better code design and is an Uncle Bob favourite. However, my colleague argues that it is so much more expensive to new-up an object every time we want to call this method.

Is he correct?

**Further Explanation**

- Utility class doesn't exist. I just wanted to put the methods in a class for you all to see. In actuality it's in a sensible class.
- There were, in fact, 5 AddHistoryEntry methods in the original code. All of which took a lot of int parameters. One reason for the refactoring was that `AddHistory(0, 1, 45, 3);` doesn't really tell you much!
- AddHistoryEntry is not called from a tight loop, but it is widely used throughout the application.

**Corrections**

I've now updated the code examples as I had made a mistake with some of the parameters.

Comment: Unless the code is going to be run on a toaster, I would always choose the most readable, easy-to-maintain version. Premature Optimization is the root of all evil - http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: The **this** keyword is almost never required in C#. If you're concerned about clean code, eliminate it. This isn't Java.

Comment: @DavidLively: I agree and never use it in my code. However, the Stack Overflow markup engine wanted it.

Comment: God, I *hate* that premature optimization root of all evil thing. Programmers hear it, and they suddenly stop thinking about performance.

Comment: @David Lively: StyleCop requires the use of *this* http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/a-difference-of-style.aspx

Comment: The "this" requirement is configurable in StyleCop, as it should be.

Comment: @DavidLively: stumbling over this old comment i wondered if it's really _unclean_ to append _this_. Actually it adds the value that the variable is a member and not within method scope. Isn't it cleaner then? (btw, you don't need to append it in java neither)

Comment: @TimSchmelter the issue I have is that you wind up with 20 line methods where *every* line starts with `this.`. In my opinion, that makes the code noisy. Instead, I stick to a naming convention that makes it clear what's local and what's not. Local variables and method parameters are `camelCase`, public fields and properties are `PascalCase`, and private properties and fields `_lookLikeThis`. When looking at a screen with 50 lines of code, 200 instances of `this.` creates an unnecessary distraction and aggravates my ADD.

Comment: @TimSchmelter also, you're obviously right about Java - until recently, though, every piece of Java code I came across made excessive use of `this.`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

He might be correct if you have millions of these objects in memory simultaneously.  But if you don't, then he's bringing up what is almost certainly a moot point.  Always choose a better design first, and then modify it only if you're not meeting performance requirements.

Answer (score 20):

Creating a new object is very cheap. You'd have to create a lot of objects in a very tight loop to notice any difference... but at the same time, it's not *free*. You also need to bear in mind that the costs are half hidden - you have some cost upfront when you create the object, but also it means the garbage collector has more work to do.

So is a cleaner design worth the performance hit? We can't tell you that - it depends on how your code is used. I strongly suspect the performance hit will be insignificant, but if you *are* using this in a tight loop, it may not be. There's only one way to find out though: measure it if you're concerned. Personally I'd probably just go for the cleaner design and only check the performance when it looked like it was becoming a problem.

(If this method is hitting disk or a database, by the way, the difference is almost *bound* to be insignificant.)

One suggestion, by the way: does your `HistoryEntry` type actually need to be mutable? Could you make all the properties read-only, backed by private read-only variables?

Just to mention Will's point - I somewhat agree with him. If these two methods are the *only* places you need this concept, I'm not at all sure it's worth creating a new type for the sake of it. Not because of the performance aspect, but just because you're introducing an extra bunch of code for no demonstrated benefit. The key word here is demonstrated - if you're actually using the same collection of parameters in other places, or could usefully put logic into the `HistoryEntry` class, that's a different matter entirely.

EDIT: Just to respond to the point about multiple integer arguments - C# 4 will allow named arguments which should make this easier. So you could call:

```
AddHistoryEntry(userId: 1, companyId: 10);
```

Making the names visible with an additional class needs one of:

- Named constructor arguments from C# 4 (in which case you're no better off than with the method)
- Mutable types (urgh - that could lead to hard to trace bugs which wouldn't have been in the original version)
- Long static method names to construct instances ("FromUserAndCompanyId") which become unwieldy with more parameters
- A mutable builder type
- A bunch of "With" methods: `new HistoryEntry().WithCompanyId(...).WithUserId(...)` - this makes it harder to validate at compile-time that you've provided all the required values.

Comment: +1 for mentioning refactoring with very little DRY benefit (conceptual benefit notwithstanding).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not so sure about the refactoring remarks (talking to you too here, Will!). The single most beneficial refactoring technique  (well, *potentially* beneficial, and I *might* be exaggerating a little) doesn't have any DRY benefit: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/renameMethod.html.

Comment: @Jeff: Note that I didn't actually mention DRY - I just said there was no demonstrated benefit, and I still believe that's the case. The term "HistoryEntry" is already present in the first form (in the method name) so it's not adding any context there...

Comment: agreed, and in retrospect I realize my remark was a non-sequiter; the primary motivation for the extract class refactoring is to avoid repeating ones' self, while that's not true for rename method (which would have to justify itself by actually correcting a  bad method name).

Comment: My wife has been reading this over my shoulder and asked 'What does DRY mean again?'. Priceless.

Answer (score 5):

Why not a static method in the class itself?

`public static void AddHistoryEntry(HistoryEntry entry)`

Saves you the utility class. The new object may be expensive, it may not--but it probably doesn't matter. Good defaults allow you to extend your code much more easily, and you'll save more time in maintenance than you do in performance, unless you're doing this in a loop.

Comment: AddHistoryEntry should really be a member of SOME useful object, no? It doesn't operate in a vacuum. But if you absolutely need a static utility class, ok... fine. Would AddHistoryEntry be better off as part of a class like History.. so you could say myHistory.addHistoryEntry(HistoryEntry entry) ?

Comment: We really can't assume that it's possible to make that into a static method when we don't know anything about what the method really does.  Static methods with side-effects are also generally a bad idea.  Sorry, but that's a -1.

Comment: I've responded to this in my main question.

Answer (score 5):

You're both wrong, but he's more wrong than you.

Comment: Okay, I can see it coming, so I'll be more clear.  You're refactoring (it appears) for refactoring's sake and he's optimizing prematurely.

Comment: +1, although far more for the comment than the actual answer. (I suggest you edit.) I've touched on this in an edit to my answer, too.

Comment: @jon I know, its more appropriate in the answer.  However, the artist in me refuses to destroy a beautiful (eye, beholder) reply for practical reasons.  It can be read so many ways and therefore spurs the mind to think about the implications of the path you take through another's code.  Or something.

Comment: "He" may be "optimizing prematurely" or just be ignorant of design.

Comment: The reason I refactored it was that it was hard to understand in its current state.

Comment: @chris just going on the tip of the code-iceberg, you know.  It does seem a bit pointless... but I have to say pointless refactoring is one of my guilty pleasures.

Answer (score 4):

It's expensive relative to *not* creating objects in .NET, in the same way that 1 is a large number relative to 0.  It all depends on your perspective.  If this is in a loop that's being run 20 million times, I might worry; otherwise, I wouldn't care.

Having said that, I'd like to point out that `Utility` is not a good name for a class, and refactoring into a `HistoryEntry` also likely requires you to verify that the parameter being passed in is not `null`, a requirement that you did not have originally when all parameters were value types.

It's also commonly considered an anti-pattern to have objects with data but no behaviour, which `HistoryEntry` seems to be.  Try to avoid doing this too often.

Comment: +1 for `Utility`.  Just chunk everything into a single class called "Stuff" whydontcha?

Comment: Unless he's building a customer action history list for their Pacific Gas & Electric call center incidents.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really expensive to create objects in .NET. In fact, object creation is *very* fast, even if you create millions of them.

However, garbage collection is *not* cheap. If you create a lot of short-lived objects, you may experience considerable slowdown when gc kicks in. It makes sense to avoid creating new short-lived objects if creation runs thousands or millions of times. If, for example, you create several objects with every network packet received by a server with thousands of connections.

That said, it is never wise to avoid calling `new` *before* demonstrating that lots of objects really *do* slow down gc. In your example, they most probably would not.

Answer (score 1):

Is this really a performance bottleneck? If not, then it would be a clear case of premature optimization to avoid using objects in this case. Maintainability and design should take priority over performance until you start hitting significant performance issues.

Comment: I think @Chris Arnold was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly more computationally expensive, but for that cost you get the benefit of cleaner, more conceptual code that can more quickly respond to future business demands. Performance vs agility.

Answer (score 0):

No. The garbage collector is optimized to be highly efficient when dealing with short-lived objects.